# The docker stable repository is not signed?

Tags: security, repository, docker

I found that the docker stable repository is not signed, and I can't believe that. Can anyone confirm please?

Following https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository, the *"set up the stable repository"* section:

```
% add-apt-repository \
>    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
>    $(lsb_release -cs) \
>    stable"
. . . 
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

$ apt-cache policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: I would file a bug report to get this fixed if I used docker (which I don't). On the other hand nVidia drivers (or something like that) aren't signed and taint the kernel but I don't care enough to file a bug report. And if I did file a bug report I don't think they care enough to fix it. Docker on the other hand may be different and would care to fix the problem.